# How to delete elements from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

How do I delete the integer at the given index and how do I compress `myInts`?

This is what I got but I keep getting an error.

```
public void deleteInt(int index) {

    int[] newInts = Arrays.copyOf(myInts, myInts.length);

    if (myInts[index] != 0) {
        myInts[index] = 0;

        for (int i : myInts) {
            if (myInts[i] != 0) {
                newInts[i] = myInts[i];
            }
        }
    }
    myInts = newInts;
    currentInt++;
}
```

This is the error I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems like a reasonable question, just needed some more detail.

Comment: @DonBranson guess they just dont know how to do it so they down vote, but anyways do you have an idea of how id go about it without using an arraylist?

Comment: I think ArrayList would be a good approach. Is there a reason not to?

Comment: Because there is no obvious question here.  What does it mean to 'delete an integer'?  Does it mean to remove the integer from memory and free up the space it was taking?  Does it mean to shift all other integers from the array down by one index?  Also, it's not particularly useful just to say 'keep getting an error'.

Comment: @SimonC, he added the specific error before your comment. :) Also, he question doesn't say 'delete an integer' it says 'delete the integer at the given index' and that's crystal-clear.

Comment: @DonBranson, no, it's not crystal-clear at all.  You can make some assumptions about what the OP actually means, but the wording in itself is ambiguous.  There were are at least 4 other people who agreed with me when the post was closed as ambiguous.  

Also, the revision timestamps don't give enough granularity to prove the error was added after my comment, but I can assure you it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code doesn't use the enhanced for loop properly:

```
    for (int i : myInts) {
        if (myInts[i] != 0) {
            newInts[i] = myInts[i];
        }
    }
```

It tries to read element i from myInts, but i is the content of an element, not its index.  So, as soon as some element contains a value > array's length you the the outofbounds exception.

```
public void deleteInt(int index) {

    // can be 1 element shorter as we are going to erase 1 element
    // also, copying the contents of the original array in is a waste of time
    // so we just create it.
    int[] newInts = new int[myInts.length-1]; 

    // the easiest way is to use an extra variable to track the insertions in the
    // new array
    int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i < myInts.length; i++) {
        if (i != index) {
            newInts[j++] = myInts[i];
        }
    }

    // so now we have a new shortened copy of the array, but as the function is void,
    // its life ends here :)
}
```

Comment: this just copys the index to the end but does not delete it

Comment: if i have array 1,2,3,4,5 and do deleteInt(3); i should get 1,2,3,5

Comment: the edited version does what you want and also points to a remaining issue with your code - without solving it as you just admitted it's homework :)

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly, and i fixed the remaining issue. Thanks for all your help

Comment: You're welcome!  Now, maybe you could extend the exercise a bit to keep it interesting and adapt my code to do the deletion in place, ie, create a shortened version of myInts without using newInts. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

For that you should use something like `ArrayList`. Using `Array` leads you to making code like in your exaple which is generally a very bad idea from quality and performance perspective.

**EDIT:** See code below:

```
ArrayList<int> ret = new ArrayList<int>(Arrays.asList(myInts));
ret.remove(index);
return ret.toArray();
```

Comment: I know how to do it with arraylist, i need to use regular array because it is what is being asked to do.

Answer (score 2):

So, first the unit test:

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ArrayExample_UT {

    @InjectMocks
    private ArrayExample subject;

    int[] testArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int[] expectedArray = {1, 2, 4, 5};

    @Test
    public void testThat_RemoveEntry_RemovesCorrectEntry() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(Arrays.equals(expectedArray, subject.removeEntry(2, testArray)));
    }
}
```

Then, some code that runs green:

```
package com.example;

class ArrayExample {

    public int[] removeEntry(int skipIndex, int[] sourceArray){
        int[] newArray = new int[sourceArray.length - 1];
        int targetIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; i++){
            if(i != skipIndex){
                newArray[targetIndex++] = sourceArray[i];
            }
        }
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all your help and for actually staying to help this long, but i got the answer from someone else before i saw your post sorry

Comment: +1 for giving an answer that's production quality, including unit test!